# Programming Intel i3 like RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, programming, microprocessor, home-automation, intel

I am building a fairly large home automation system comprising of cameras and other sensors. I experimented with a Raspberry Pi, but it simply wasn't able to handle the load. Therefore I want to know if an Intel i3 can be programmed and used directly from the motherboard.

I know it sounds ridiculous but I'm on a budget and I happen to have an old i3 processor. If yes, what kind of operating system would be my best choice or is it possible to program it baremetal without an OS? Both of these would be great but i would prefer baremetal despite the steep learning curve.

If anyone has done baremetal programming on i3, please post a few links.

Comment: have you tried baremetal programming with the RPi. write asm for arm

Comment: @JonRB yeah , i have tried with rpi

Comment: @jippie, never seen baremetal in Computer Science discussions

Comment: @jippie i thought some people here might have worked on it like a hobby project , or could atleast direct me to some links,

Comment: I don't think that this type of question is a good fit for Stack Exchange. It's basically just give me the links. If you need assembly programming advice, StackOverflow can be a good solution. If you want to do simple assembler programming. check out assembler operating systems. One example would be MikeOS. Another option I've tried is MenuetOS. There's also for example BareMetal, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Plenty of questions about programming AVRs and PICs so why not Intel i3?

Comment: PIC and AVR are embedded microcontrollers.  An i3 is not, it is a full-blown microprocessor that is extremely complex and is capable of running a full desktop OS.  So it is really a better fit over at stack overflow.

Comment: This project sounds like an enormous undertaking, and something that would take a single person years to finish, if they got that far...

Comment: That's true, but I think it's more about the question than the processor. After all an ARM processor can be a microcontroller but can also run a full desktop OS. If the question was about how to connect an Intel i3 up to a PCI bus then it seems like a reasonable question for EESE. If it's about how to implement a linked list on an AVR then SO. To me a question about implementing firmware for an i3 is closer to the EE side of things.

Comment: Try using more powerful device for automation : [pine64](https://www.pine64.com/) or [banana pi](http://www.bananapi.org/) **Os with i3 processor :** ubuntu, fedora, linux mint,

Comment: Yes, you can use an older PC motherboard running something like Linux for embedded control, but it will be power hungry and poor in real-world I/O compared to ARM, etc boards made for that purpose.  Still, with care (and possibly USB I/O delegates) it can work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it's possible to build and run an i3-based computer with no OS. How do you think the OS starts up in the first place? But it's a very deep and complicated stack.

I assume that what you have is an Intel i3 mounted on a regular PC motherboard. If you only have a bare processor, just put it down and back away. It has hundreds of pins ferchrissakes.

Intel processors start up more or less the same way they did 30 years ago, when everyone was running DOS. The processor starts up in real mode and begins executing code at address 0xFFFFFFF0. (If you're familiar with Intel real mode you might recognize this address as being 16 bytes from the end of the real mode memory space.) If you burn your program into flash memory at this address, the processor will run it. Assuming your motherboard supports upgrading the firmware (most do now), this should be possible. But you're going to be in real mode, so unless your program can run in one megabyte of memory, you'll have to figure out how to set up protected mode, then figure out out how to access peripherals, etc.  Is that what you want?

Or, if what you have is really a PC with an i3, you could let the processor boot into the existing firmware on the board and then let the firmware load your code from a device like a hard drive or USB storage device instead of the OS. But you're still in more or less the same position, running at a very low level in a very complex environment.

I found [this document from Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-boot-loader-development-kit/minimal-intel-architecture-boot-loader-paper.html) that summarizes the "minimum steps" necessary to boot an Intel processor. It's 26 pages long.